# Average for partition bounded by last 7 days

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a query spanned across last 30 days, which sums total revenue, however I also want along with sum of last 30 days, add average of last 7 days. I want something like this:

```
select 
    country 
    , avg(revenue) over (partition by country range between current_date - 7 and current_date) avg_revenue_last_7_days
    , sum(revenue) total_revenue_30_days
from table 
group by 1,2
```

Is it possible to get average for a smaller number of days than what aggregation is based on?

I want to avoid subqueries because the query already quite complex.

Comment: How can you GROUP BY 2? And don't tag irrelevant products.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results . . . or at least your data layout.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need window functions for this, just conditional aggregation:

```
select country,
       avg(case when datecol between current_date - 7 and current_date
                then revenue
           end) as avg_revenue_last_7_days,
       sum(case when datecol between current_date - 30 and current_date
                then revenue
           end) as total_revenue_30_days
from table 
group by country;
```

Comment: ... and I'd add `WHERE datecol >= CURRENT_DATE - 30` to minimise the rows to GROUP BY ...